# VUE: API polling not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to poll radio server API (that I have no control over) to update the current playing song on the client side in my NuxtJs app. While it works as intended on the desktop (currently playing track updates and console log shows the polling every 5 seconds), it doesn't update while I test it on any mobile device.

Here is my code:

```
    methods: {
      pollData() {
    
        this.polling = setInterval(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch('getNowPlaying')
        }, 5000)
      },

   computed: {
   ...mapGetters({
        nowPlaying: 'nowPlaying'
   })
```

Are mobile devices disabling such polling by default due to performance issues? Is there an alternative method, taking into account that I don't control the API?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the culprit here. Are you sure you have nothing else not working here? Also, maybe try to make something visual (like appending a block to somewhere or printing a notification) to debug this one. The issue is probably coming from somewhere else. https://caniuse.com/?search=setinterval

Comment: what happens if you use device emulation in your desktop browser?

Comment: @Keith I figured out how to display the console on my mobile device and I see there is a CORS error between my domain and the API domain. So this must be the cause...

Comment: You need to wuitelist the local IP of your phone. Check your router to find this one out. Or in the phone settings somewhere maybe.